# Crop the blank part of the image on PHP

Tags: php, gd

I am developing application where I need to crop the empty part (white part) of the image to move it left. The picture format is JPEG and only 2 colors are used: white (background) and black (signature). Please see for below for a sample. How to do this on PHP?[image: Sample of the image]

Comment: If you want the image to stay the same size you'll need to extend the height and width back to the original values, but that should be a much easier problem to solve

Comment: The main question is how to crop that white part of the image.

Comment: Then the suggested duplicate about cropping whitespace should be everything you need